# How to write a regex to match multiple file path

Tags: python, regex

I have want to match files located in multiple directories:

The file path could be locally - **C:/users/path/image.png** or on a system - /**/home/user/web/image.png**

For the first case, I have regular expression -

```
[c|C]:[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3}
```

How can I have a single regex to match both of the cases?

Comment: I tried - image_path = re.findall(r"(([c|C]:)|(//home))[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3}", str(list1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to get from the match is not clear - maybe you just want the full string?

```
((?:(?:[cC]:)|//home)[^\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})
```

A dot (`.`) will match (close to) everything. If you want to compare and contrast against the string `.`, you should escape it with `\.`.

Test runs:

```
>>> print re.match("((?:(?:[cC]:)|//home)[^\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})", "//home/user/web/image.png").groups()
('//home/user/web/image.png',)

>>> print re.match("((?:(?:[cC]:)|//home)[^\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})", "C:/users/path/image.png").groups()
('C:/users/path/image.png',)
```

And one for the usual Windows path syntax:

```
>>> print re.match("((?:(?:[cC]:)|//home)[^\.]+\.[A-Za-z]{3})", "C:\users\path\image.png").groups()
('C:\\users\\path\\image.png',)
```

If there's a need to support `.jpeg`, increase the max allowed occurrences for the extensions from `{3}` to `{3,4}`.

Comment: Thanks leon solution and explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
((c|C|//home)[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OShz3hq1ySmk3j6w)

If you want to use `findall()`, all the matches will be presented in a list of tuples. The tuples contain the groups in the regex, and that's the crux of the regex above - the whole expression has to be a group itself to show up in the return value of `findall()`. See the following code

```
smth = "//home/user/web/image.png C:/users/path/image.png c:/web/image.png"
ip = re.findall("((c|C|//home)[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3})",smth)
print ip
[('//home/user/web/image.png', '//home'), ('C:/users/path/image.png', 'C'), ('c:/web/image.png', 'c')]
```

Comment: This (([c|C]:)|(//home))[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3} didn't work for me. I got result to be [('C:', 'C:', ''),('//home', '', '//home')]

Comment: image_path = re.findall(r"(([c|C]:)|(//home))[^.]+[.][A-Za-z]{3}", str(list1))