# A general regex to extract file paths (not urls)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse urls and filepaths from files using Python.  I already have a url regex.

**Issue**

I want a regex pattern that extracts file paths from a string. Requirements:

- exclusive (does not include urls)
- OS-independent, i.e. Windows and UNIX style paths e.g. (`C:\`, `\\`, `/`)
- all path types, i.e. absolute & relative paths e.g. (`/`, `../`)

*Please assist by modifying my attempt below or suggesting an improved pattern.*

**Attempt**

Here is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/IsmBeL/6) I have so far:

```
(?:[A-Z]:|\\|(?:\.{1,2}[\/\\])+)[\w+\\\s_\(\)\/]+(?:\.\w+)*
```

*Description*

- `(?:[A-Z]:|\\|(?:\.{1,2}[\/\\])+)`: any preceding drive letter, backslash or dotted path
- `[\w+\\\s_\(\)\/]+`: any path-like characters - alphanumerics, slashes, parens, underscores, ...
- `(?:\.\w+)*`: optional extension

*Result*

[image]

Note: I have confirmed these results in Python using an input list of strings and the `re` module.

*Expected*

This regex satisfies most of my requirements - namely excluding urls while extracting most file paths.  However, I would like to match **all** paths (including UNIX-style paths that begin with a single slash, e.g. `/foo/bar.txt`) without matching urls.

**Research**

I have not found a general solution.  Most work tends to satisfy specific cases.

SO Posts

- [How to write a regex to match multiple file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387009/how-to-write-a-regex-to-match-multiple-file-path)
- [Regex for extracting filename from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363145/regex-for-extracting-filename-from-path)
- [regex for finding file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618116/regex-for-finding-file-paths)
- [Python regular expression for Windows file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505483/python-regular-expression-for-windows-file-path)

External sites

- [Validate a Windows Path](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s18.html)
- [Regex that matches path, filename and extension](https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/regex-that-matches-path-filename-and-extension/)

Comment: You could match the preceding character if it is going to be portable. You shouldn't use non-capturing groups either. Try this https://regex101.com/r/IsmBeL/8

Comment: And check this for Python https://regex101.com/r/IsmBeL/10

Comment: Or perhaps add another alternation with a negative lookbehind to match the first 2 paths https://regex101.com/r/5Dyith/1

Comment: Well, this is going to be fun. `command.com` is literally a filename and an internet host.

Comment: @melpomene It doesn't have an scheme? It's not a URL.

Comment: @revo OP lists `www.google.com` under "URLs".

Comment: To match that a **file** name is valid in UNIX you do this: `'\0' not in filename and filename[-1] != '/'`. The **only** limitation is that the filename cannot include `\0` and a file cannot contain `/` in its *name* (obviously its absolute path will contain `/`s). (I might add that using normal APIs you really cannot include `/` in the name part of the filename except as placing it at the end of the name... in other positions it will be interpreted as separator in the path).

Comment: @melpomene But at least never listed `google.com`.

Comment: @revo `mkdir https && touch https://www.example.com`

Comment: @melpomene Sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: @revo: What melpomene and Bakuriu are saying is, `https://www.example.com` is a valid filename. For that matter, `is a valid filename` is a valid filename. There is no way to find "filenames" in text without testing virtually every substring against a filesystem for existence.

Comment: @Amadan So they were trying to say `mkdir https: ...`. Well to me it is over-thinking and over-complicating things which usually happens. Which UNIX utility does output double slashes as part of the path? None. So this could be handled with no further sophistication. BTW, I agree with you. I never said a regex is able to sense filenames.

Comment: @revo Yours works in many of my tests.  Can you post an answer explaining your lookbehind?  See my updated tests https://regex101.com/r/IsmBeL/26.  Can you resolve the remaining issues?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you also post an answer?  See my updated tests. https://regex101.com/r/5Dyith/2

Answer (score 4):

You could split the problem in 3 alternative patterns:
*(note that I didn't implement all character exclusions for path/file names)*

- Non-quoted Windows paths
- quoted Windows paths
- unix paths

This would give something like this:

```
((((?<!\w)[A-Z,a-z]:)|(\.{1,2}\\))([^\b%\/\|:\n\"]*))|("\2([^%\/\|:\n\"]*)")|((?<!\w)(\.{1,2})?(?<!\/)(\/((\\\b)|[^ \b%\|:\n\"\\\/])+)+\/?)
```

Broken down:

```
Wind-Non-Quoted: ((((?<!\w)[A-Z,a-z]:)|(\.{1,2}\\))([^\b%\/\|:\n\"]*))
Wind-Quoted:     ("\2([^%\/\|:\n\"]*)")
Unix:            ((?<!\w)(\.{1,2})?(?<!\/)(\/((\\\b)|[^ \b%\|:\n\"\\\/])+)+\/?)


Wind-Non-Quoted:
    prefix: (((?<!\w)[A-Z,a-z]:)|(\.{1,2}\\))
         drive: ((?<!\w)[A-Z,a-z]:) *Lookback to ensure single letter*
      relative: (\.{1,2}\\))
      path: ([^\b%\/\|:\n\"]*))     *Excluding invalid name characters (The list is not complete)*

Wind-Quoted:
    prefix: \2                *Reuses the one from non-Quoted*
      path: ([^%\/\|:\n\"]*)  *Save as above but does not exclude spaces*

Unix:
    prefix: (?<!\w)(\.{1,2})?                . or .. not preceded by letters
      path: (?<!\/)                          repeated /name (exclusions as above)
            (\/((\\\b)|[^ \b%\|:\n\"\\\/])+) not preceded by /
            \/?                              optionally ending with /

            *(excluding the double slashes is intended to prevent matching urls)*
```

Comment: I appreciate the work.  Your approach does match a majority of my tests (https://regex101.com/r/qFDLwB/1/).   However, most are doing multiple captures.  Instead, I think you need multiple *non-capture* groups and one capture group to extract a cohesive file path.  See alternative: https://regex101.com/r/IsmBeL/26.  Also, are you able to resolve the remaining edge cases?